# vuejs router in loop

Tags: vue.js, router

I have below beforeEach code in my vue js. I need to only check for loggedIn and not authRequired. If I remove the authRequired from the if condition, this function looks. Is there any other way I can just check localstorage value and not check authRequired.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const publicPages = ['/login', '/register'];
  const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user');

  if (authRequired && !loggedIn) {
    return next('/login');
  }

  next();
})
```

I have tried before code. Which gets stuck in continuous loop.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const publicPages = ['/login', '/register'];
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user');

  if (!loggedIn) {
    return next('/login');
  }

  next();
})
```

Comment: `if (authRequired && !loggedIn) { next('/login');} else { next(); }`

Comment: if (!loggedIn && to.path !== '/login') { return next('/login') }

Comment: @User28 there will be more that one public path. And path as to redirect to its own public path.

Comment: What do you mean `And path as to redirect to its own public path`? Because from your code you only redirect to `/login`.

Comment: @User28 thats why i said. whatever public path it comes from, redirect to the same public path.

Comment: Oh i just understand so sorry. And I think @elad-frizi is good.

Comment: I posted a solution I found for vue-router v4.x here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68009594/1219079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any way If you want to keep using the global guards (the router.beforeEach).
If you are willing to stop using the global route guards you can use the `beforeEnter` and apply it to every route manually. In this solution will be able to use the second function on every route except the 'login' route.

```
const authGuard = (to,from,next) => {
  const loggedIn = localStorage.getItem('user');

  if (!loggedIn) {
      return next('/login');
    }

    next();
}

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/login',
        component: Login
    },
    {
        path: '/someProtectedRoute',
        component: Bar,
        beforeEnter: authGuard
    },
    {
        path: '/anotherProtcted',
        component: Bar,
        beforeEnter: authGuard
    }
]
```